# JPA Criteria API With Named Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api, named-query

The title says it all: is it possible to use a named query inside of a query built with the JPA criteria API ? Something along the lines of (simple example):

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "complexFooQuery", query = "FROM Foo where ....")
class Foo {
    ////....
}

List<Foo> getFoo() {
    CriteriaQuery<Foo> cq = em.createQuery(Foo.class);
    cq.select(<somehow specify complex foo named query>);
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. 
Criteria queries are constructed dynamically (so to give typesafe handling) ... and if just dumping some named query in then there would be no typesafe handling. Besides, a subquery is illegal in the SELECT clause for strict JPQL (and a JPQL query starts with "SELECT {alias}" too FWIW)

Comment: You can still use Strings for property names though right? In that case type-safe isn't explicit.

Comment: Well theoritically yes, but String column names don't work for me; had to generate metamodel beforhand, and then get column with sth like `root.get(MyEntity_.userId)`. Thus type safety is secured.